# i want to generate a sample request and response for a operation from a wsdl in java , i have soap-ws but it need wsdl url , but i need something w

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, wsdl

Problem:
I am using the soap-ws library (https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws) for working with SOAP in Java. The library provides functionality to parse a WSDL from a URL, but I need to parse a WSDL from a content string instead.

What I Need:
I want to modify the WSDL class in the soap-ws library to accept a WSDL content string rather than a URL.

What I Have Tried:
I have examined the library's code and identified the constructor that accepts a URL. I made a modification to accept a String instead by using ByteArrayInputStream.

public class WSDL {

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(WSDL.class);
private Definition definition;

public WSDL(String wsdlContent) throws WSDLException, IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsdlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        definition = WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader().readWSDL(null, new InputSource(is));
    }
}
```

String wsdlContent = "Your WSDL Content as a String";
WSDL wsdl = new WSDL(wsdlContent);

What I Have Tried:
I have examined the library's code and identified the constructor that accepts a URL. I made a modification to accept a String instead by using ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.